# How to make a makefile only for compiling some java files?

Tags: java, compilation, makefile

I have three java files named A.java, B.java, C.java, A will create object B, B will create object C. But I have never built a makefile before. Does anyone can help me build a makefile just to compile these three java files? And what tool should I use to make a makefile? Thank you!

Comment: Simple answer.  Use Maven or Ant or Gradle for building Java.

Answer (score 2):

1. Define your suffixes.
2. Define how to turn .java into .class
3. Define what classes you want
4. Define an "all" target.

You don't need any specific editor for making a makefile; even Notepad would do.

Comment: I have write my makefile, but when I run "make". Aludra shows me: make : Fatal error : No arguments to build. What's wrong?

Comment: @Ziyu - What is wrong is that your Makefile doesn't define a default target.